# google calendar api net api The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm new to google api. I'm using google .net api, I'm getting the error:

**The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error**

I'm able to see the login screen, I accept the permissions request, and I got redirected to Index 2 correctly. When the calendar service is going to be used (execute) it crashes with the already mentioned error.

I already set the token as offline in the GOOGLE_AUTH_URL_TEMPLATE variable. That is supposed to be used for long term tokens.

Main Auth Class

```
public class TestOAuth2
{
    private string applicationName = "g calendar test api";
    private string clientId = "---";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
    private string clientSecret = "---";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
    private string[] scopes = new string[] {
                        CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
                        CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
                      };
    private UserCredential userCredential;
    string GOOGLE_AUTH_URL_TEMPLATE = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&scope={0}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&login_hint=";
    string clientRedirectUri= "http://localhost:57618/Home/Index2";
    private CalendarService calendarService;

    public TestOAuth2(string access_token)
    {
        ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        };

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;
        TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse
        {
            AccessToken = access_token
        };
        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
            Scopes = scopes
        });

        userCredential = new UserCredential(flow, "user", token);
calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });
    }

    public string GetGoogleOAuthURL()
    {
        return string.Format(GOOGLE_AUTH_URL_TEMPLATE, String.Join("+", scopes), clientRedirectUri, clientId);
    }

    private void InitializeCalendarService()
    {
        calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });
        
    }

    public string GetEvents()
    {
        try
        {
            if (calendarService == null)
            {
                InitializeCalendarService();
            }
            var eventRequest = calendarService.Events.List("primary");
            eventRequest.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            eventRequest.ShowDeleted = false;
            eventRequest.SingleEvents = true;
            eventRequest.MaxResults = 10;
            eventRequest.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
            var events = eventRequest.Execute();

            string sEvents = "";
            foreach (var evt in events.Items)
            {
                sEvents += evt.Description + "\n<br>";
            }
            return sEvents;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Home Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private TestOAuth2 Google;
        
        public string GetGoogleOauthUrl()
        {
            string temp = "";
            try
            {
                Google = new TestOAuth2(string.Empty);
                temp = Google.GetGoogleOAuthURL();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                temp = ex.Message;
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public string GetEvents()
        {
            string access_token = Request.Headers.Get("access_token");
            string temp = "";
            try
            {
                Google = new TestOAuth2(access_token);
                temp = Google.GetEvents();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                temp = ex.Message;
            }
            return temp;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index2()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index View

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
        fetch("http://localhost:57618/Home/GetGoogleOauthUrl", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    response.text().then(myAnswer => {
                        console.log(myAnswer);
                        window.open(myAnswer, '_blank');
                    })
                } else {
                    console.error.log("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
                }
            });
    });

    

</script>
Hello! Wait For A New Window!
</body>
</html>
```

Index 2 View

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function getUrlParameter(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
            var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
            var results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        };

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {

            let token = getUrlParameter("code");
            fetch("http://localhost:57618/Home/GetEvents", {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        "access_token": token
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            response.text().then(myAnswer => {
                                console.log(myAnswer);
                                document.write("<br><br><br>");
                                document.write(myAnswer);
                            })
                        } else {
                            console.error.log("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
                        }
                    });
        
        });



    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a special token that does not need to be refreshed I believe.
To do that you need to create a project inside GCP and then create a Service Account and Download a json key inside the new Service Account created.
Enable the Calendar API inside the new created project and copy the email of the service account. Go to the calendar you want to give access to your api and add the email you copy from the service account. Now you can use the service account json key to authenticate and it wont have expiration.